# What is the function that best fits this curve

Tags: probability-distributions, graphing-functions, curves

I'd like to know what is the function that best fits this curve:

[image]

**Edit**
In fact I am a software developer and I need to use this function for a *naive* random number generattion for a lifetime of people. The answer of my dreams include the equation as a function of the mean and standard deviation.

Thanks

Comment: May be, you could precise the context of the question.

Comment: My focus is on lifetime expectation but here I am asking in general

Comment: In general, there are probably many many functions which look like this.

Comment: Can you please link me to any or some of them?

Comment: I prefer a simple one that can be used in my software development

Comment: "I am asking in general": there are milion answers to this question in general. Do you know anything about the behavior at endpoints ?

Comment: Going by the sketch, it could be a solution to the KdV equation, in the form,  $u(x, t) = \sech^{2}(x-ct)$

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I am not a scientist, I guessed that any of experts here can, at a glance, guess what is this. Exactly like me guessing the sinusoidal wave, Gaussian curve, or other common curves. I'll edit my answer to add more details about my problem.

Comment: @mmonem: yep, at a glance you can find ten different functions that fit, not counting the free form curves. To give an answer that makes sense some insight about where the curve is coming from is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Skew normal distribution may be of interest to you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution

I tried: $ y=e^{-x^2/2}(1+erf(-3x))$ which has something looking similar to what you want.

(See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3De%5E%7B-x%5E2%2F2%7D(1%2Berf(-3x)))

It uses the erf function though, which may be tricky to plot using some softwares.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing me to the skew normal distribution which seems very close but the function based on the error function you are giving is not

Comment: Sorry, the example you provided based on the error function is great

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough with a qualitative fit rather than high accuracy, Hermite cubic interpolation should be good enough. It allows you to specify the ordinates and slopes at the endpoints.

In the given case, it reduces to $x^2(1-x)$. If you want a flatter curve on the left, try $x^n(1-x)$.

The mean and standard deviation can be adjusted by a mapping $x\to\dfrac{x-\mu}\sigma$.

Comment: Very simple and helpful. It looks good for n = 4. I just realized that the falling edge nearing zero is not as realistic as the original curve.